Why assume $x = a\secθ$?

Not every real number $x$ can be represented as $x = a\sec\left(\theta\right)$ where a is a real number.
Like in case where $x < a$ i.e. $\sec\left(\theta\right) \not\in \left(−1,1\right)$.
If so then why are we assuming random $x$ to be
$a\sec\left(\theta\right)$ ?.

I saw this solution from my book.
Example 1
Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{x^2 - a^2} \, dx$
Solution:
Let $x = a \sec \theta$. Then, $dx = a \sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta$.
$$
\therefore \int \frac{1}{x^2 - a^2} \, dx = \int \frac{a \sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta}{a^2 \sec^2 \theta - a^2}
$$
$$
= \int \frac{a \sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta}{a^2 \sec^2 \theta - a^2}
$$
$$
= \int \frac{a \sec \theta \tan \theta \, d\theta}{a^2 \tan^2 \theta}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{\sec \theta}{\tan \theta} \, d\theta = \frac{1}{a} \int \csc \theta \, d\theta
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{a} \log \left| \csc \theta - \cot \theta \right| + c
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{a} \log \left| \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}} - \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}} \right| + c
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{a} \log \left| \frac{x - a}{\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}} \right| + c
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{a} \log \left| \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{x + a}} \right| + c
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2a} \log \left| \frac{x - a}{x + a} \right| + c
$$

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: If the square root is meant to be real, what does that tell us about $x^2-a^2$?

Please format your formulas.

Very similar question from today. Also, please use $ and $$ instead of \( \) and \[ \] to format.  Why have $\sec\theta\not\in(-1,1)$?

It's not random. This is just like $u$ substitution where you're making a choice and leveraging chain rule to make the integral easier. Did you read the beginning of the section? It should explain the entire philosophy.

The function you get after integrating is undefined for $a>x$, because of the square root, as @J.G. pointed out. The domain of the result you get is $x<-a$ or $a<x$ by method of intervals

I think that J.G., Cameron Williams, and Gwen's comment do not adress the OP's (implicit) astonishment about how, though the intermediate calculations clearly assume $|x|>|a|$, they give a result which is still an antiderivative on $(-a,a)$.

Sorry, I must have misread the question as having a square root from the outside. But if we separately consider the two cases, partial fractions imply the log-mod result will look the same in both.

@Oshiet, is it really written $\log \left| \sqrt{\frac{x - a}{x + a}} \right| $ in your book? It should be $\log\sqrt{ \left| \frac{x - a}{x + a} \right| }$.

Of course, other methods (like partial fractions, or simply "guessing" and checking by differentiation) will give the same result in both cases $|x|>a$ and $|x|<a$. But that is not the question (if I understand it correctly).
